# Incorrect work redefined form in django admins

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've created custom model Profile and linked it to the User model which works fine. But, now I want to create custom UserCreateForm in Django admin. I redefined it and added necessary fields, but after that still shows, all fields from profile model, ex: phone, home_address. I need fields  displayed as : 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password1', 'password2' in the UserCreateForm. What have I done wrong?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class NewUserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

   class Meta:
       fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name',)

class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):

   add_form = NewUserCreateForm

   add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username','password1', 'password2', ),
       }),
       )
   inlines = [ProfileInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: If you would like to disable some fields from showing try `class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('first_name', 'last_name', 'username',)
 `

Comment: is it necessary to inherit from admin.ModelAdmin? I'm inherit from UserAdmin and indicated fields: phone and home_address in readonly_fields but they are still displayed. These fields I need to hide only in UserCreateForm

Comment: If i was in your shows i ll try to take advantage of `exclude` in my form inside `class Meta`. So try to change your code `exclude : ('phone', 'home_address' , )`.

Comment: I'm add exclude in Meta class form NewUserCreateForm: exclude = ('phone', 'home_address',) and still is show. If I can help, I've added the model User with help OnetoOne

Comment: In my code, if I am using this snippet :

`class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile
    readonly_fields = ('phone', 'home_address' ,)`

it works fine. Did you try it without result ?

Comment: If I change to: readonly_fields = ('first_name',) work is fine. But I tried hide field 'phone' then does not work

Comment: Try to add it in fields above and then it will.

Comment: Not working. After inline model Profile with User, all field was show when add new user, since UserCreationForm used by default model User. Override the form UserCreationForm does not help. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: A detailed version of your files (`models.py`, `forms.py`, `views.py` and `admin.py`) may be helpful.

Comment: Now i work only with Django admin. Added model Profile and linked by external key with User model. Profile model:
Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
#and other fields

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `models.py` file will be :

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

...

Then your `admin.py` file.

```
from.models import Profile
# Register your models here.


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Profile
    exclude = ['phone',] # Or whatever you don't want to display.

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

For extended implementation please add or remove based on your needs.

Hope it helps.